# Intro to Python HW assignment

Tags: python

Instructions:  Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : 
        break
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except: 
        print('Invalid input')
        continue


   if smallest is None or num < smallest :
       smallest = num
   elif largest is None or num > largest :
       largest = num

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

So after inputting 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4, and then entering done, the code will not print out the max and min numbers as I have coded in the last two lines. Where is my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using a debugger to step through the code line-by-line?

Comment: You can't use `elif` in your condition because if you enter the largest number first then this will not work. Other than that works fine, what are you seeing after you type `'done'`? (Note: I assume the single space difference in indent of the `if` condition is just a cut and paste error - otherwise you would get an `IndentationError`)

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting downvoted so heavily, but two small things you could do to improve your question: change the title to something like "Finding maximum and minimum input numbers" because that's more descriptive (and so people don't think you're trying to get them to do your homework), and include the actual output your code gives on your sample input.

Comment: `num = int(num)` will not yield an error if the input is a float (e.g. 7.2)

Comment: @ user55449 I am new to stackoverflow so thanks for the advice, will keep in mind in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can append the numbers to a list and use built-in methods to do that for you, `min()` and `max()`. For example:

```
my_list = []

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : 
        break
    try:
        num = int(num)
        my_list.append(num)
    except: 
        print('Invalid input')
        continue

largest = max(my_list)
smallest = min(my_list)

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: Although this is a correct solution. I think at this stage of learning programming, I don't think the goal of the OP's teacher is to use two variable to kept max min not a List

Answer (score 0):

It will not work in a case where the largest integer is the first input. You could try to initialize the largest and smallest variable to the first input to solve it.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : 
        break
    try:
        num = int(num)

    except: 
        print('Invalid input')
        continue

    if largest is None:
       largest,smallest = num,num
    elif num < smallest :
       smallest = num
    elif num > largest :
       largest = num

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```